# VS2010 on multiple monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, visual-studio-2010

I'm using VS2010, which has the cool feature of allowing you to drag panels out of the main IDE window. I like to drag some of the panels off to one of my other monitors.

Unfortunately, after each run/debug session, VS2010 seems to forget where I had the panels, and dumps them right in the middle of the IDE window, and I have to move it again. Does anyone know what to do about this?

Comment: That is weird, it definitely does not do that on my install. Perhaps you have a corrupted install?

Comment: It does this on multiple installations around the office

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered the answer to this. It seems my Matrox graphics card is set to automatically centre certain new windows. This is solved now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i know what to do about it.  You need to fiddle with the "nView Desktop Manager" driver settings.  It can be set a variety of different ways from treating both monitors as one monitor to treating both monitors separately, and a few other combinations of that kind of thing.    It sounds therefore like just a matter of your video driver settings.